# Brownie private keys

Tags: python, ganache, brownie

Brownie under the hood use Ganache. Ones we start `brownie console` accounts are generate automatically (10 by default) for further use.

Question: is there a way to discover private key from account[0] for example from within Brownie console?

Up date to question:
If I try to run `ganche-cli` (as proposed) it will give us private keys used inside `brownie console` and that`s ok. Now we know private keys.

[image]

[image]

But if we try to deploy some contract, while `ganache-cli` running in background and then to go into interactive mode with `brownie run script arg1 arg2 -i` interactive flag to see private keys, Brownie will stay stucked in the loop like this:

[image]

What I need is to see private keys of address from which I made this deploy in local dev environment and to add them to MetaMask connected to Ganache 8545 port and then to test front-end from deployer address (now present in MetaMask) on function that have `onlyOwner` modifier.

But to add to MetaMask we need to know private keys which are hard to obtain in explained scenario when deployment (not simple `ganche-cli` => `brownie console`) with ganache-cli running in background is involved.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use the brownie console for viewing the private keys of the default accounts that brownie uses. They are generated using the ganache-cli and their private keys will be displayed while running the cli tool.
[image]

You can, however, view the private keys of the accounts that you have [added to brownie.](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html#localaccount) Here's how [you can do it](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html#LocalAccount.private_key).

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution to my question is `brownie-config.yaml`.

I add mnemonic from which accounts should be generated (same as I have in my dev MetaMask) and Brownie generate accounts. Now when I plug MetaMask to `localhost 8545` everything worked just fine.

brownie-config.yaml part:

````
networks:
    development:
        cmd_settings:
            accounts: 20
            mnemonic: ${MNEMONIC}
            default_balance: 200 ```



Before this don't forget to put your mnemonic in .env file!
````

Answer (score 0):

setting the same mnemonic will work fine. You can also generate an account in metamask and give the private key of the account as a parameter while running ganache

```
ganache-cli --account "0x<account-private-key>"
```

I think this will also yield similar results